# Sum of multiples of 4 fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying to prove this identity
$$\sum_{i=1}^n F_{4i} = F^2_{2n+1} -1$$
So, I try to use PIM to prove.

**Base case:** $n=2$
$$\sum_{i=1}^2 F_{4i} =  3 +21=24=F_5^2 -1$$

**Inductive step**: suppose this sum is true for $k \in \mathbb{N}$
\begin{equation*}
            \sum_{i=1}^k F_{4i} = F^2_{2k+1} -1
        \end{equation*}
We want to show
\begin{equation*}
        \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} F_{4i} = F^2_{2k+3} -1
    \end{equation*}
Then
\begin{equation*}
        \sum_{i=1}^{k+1} F_{4i} =  \sum_{i=1}^k F_{4i} + F_{4k + 4} = F^2_{2k+1} -1 + F_{4k + 4}
    \end{equation*}
I'm stuck here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost there.

To finish,
you need to show that

$F^2_{2k+1} -1 + F_{4k + 4}
=F^2_{2k+3} -1
$
or
$F_{4k + 4}
=F^2_{2k+3}-F^2_{2k+1}
$.

Now use
d'Ocagne's identity
$F_{2n}
=F_{n+1}^2-F_{n-1}^2
$
with
$2n+2$ for $n$
and you are done.

Comment: I got it. Thanks!